# Any better swapping technique when implementing beam search?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a list of 20 IDs that I want to subject to beam search. The list has unique IDs i.e. none is repeated. For each IDs order, there is a value that can be computed i.e. the objective function. Basically this can just be the sum of individual values that are associated with each ID. I believe if I used brute force, then I would be required to make every combination i.e. 20 factorial combinations to come up with say the highest sum based on different combinations. I'm keen on utilising  beam search in this instance and this is my approach.

```
beam_width = 2
max_iterations = 4  

IDs =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
Values =  [10,11,23,33,23,233,22,13,78,90,9,8,10,11,45,34,45,18,19,20]

#Objective calculation function 
def objective_function(ID_order):
    
    total_performance = sum(Values[IDs.index(IDs)] for IDs in ID_order)  #sum of  values for IDs in the ID order 
    
    return total_performance
    
#beam search function   
def beam_search(IDs, beam_width, max_iterations):
    
    candidate_solutions = [(random.sample(IDs, len(IDs)), 0.0)]   # Initialize candidate  solution with a random order with 0 as the objective
    best_rule_order = None 
    best_objective = float('-inf') 
    
    for iteration in range(max_iterations):
        new_candidates = []
        #Swap rules in the  current  solution by generating  new candidate solutions
        for ID_order, _ in candidate_solutions:  
            for i in range(len(IDs)):
                new_order = ID_order[:i] + [IDs[i]] + ID_order[i+1:] #Swap ids  before calculating  the objective function
                objective = objective_function(new_order)
                new_candidates.append((new_order, objective))
        
        new_candidates.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) #Sort new  candidate solutions  in descending  order based  on the objective  value
        candidate_solutions = new_candidates[:beam_width] #Select the top candidates based on the  beam width
        #update the best ID order and objective if  a better solutions  is  found
        if candidate_solutions[0][1] > best_objective:
            best_ID_order = candidate_solutions[0][0]
            best_objective = candidate_solutions[0][1]

      
    return best_ID_order, best_objective
    
best_rule_order, best_objective = beam_search(IDs, beam_width, max_iterations)
print("Overall Best Rule Order :", best_ID_order)
print("Overall Best Objective:", best_objective)
```

My question is  specifically here `new_order = ID_order[:i] + [IDs[i]] + ID_order[i+1:]` as it duplicates some IDs except for the first iteration. Any recommendation on a better swapping technique that I can subject to the search? Basically, I'm keen on the order of IDs as that will affect the objective function in the extra bit that I'll use the code for. Therefore, I don't want any rule duplicated.

Comment: Can you explain what this data _is_ though? Because what makes you thinkg that beam search is the best solution for finding what you need to find?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Basically, I'm interested in getting the "best ordered set of  IDs" i.e., one  that  that gives the  maximum **total_performance**. Therefore, order is of  interest here in that in some  instances '''total_performance''' for IDs  1,2,3,4,5 may be  different for  IDs  2,1,3,5,4 as much as the values are the same.  Beam search may not be optimal but  from what I've read, it  gives something near optimal after a set number of  iterations. I also used beam search as a faster approach to "convergence" compared to say brute force. That's  what informed me  to use it.

Comment: `[IDs.index(IDs)] for IDs`, given that you also have a global `IDs`, is nonsense. You're going to need some disambiguation there.

Comment: If all you're doing is permuting your IDs, and your objective is the sum of `Values`, then... won't your objective always be the same?

Comment: Hello @Reinderien .  Thanks for your input. This was  just an example. However, I'll be using a different  objective  function and sum of values will not be  the same as the output of  the search  will be input in another process. All I need help on is  here new_order = ID_order[:i] + [IDs[i]] + ID_order[i+1:]. It was a naive way  so would be  happy to hear from you on a better way around this .

Comment: The solution depends on the objective. If you want a real solution, show the real objective. There's an infinite number of techniques to apply.

Comment: @Reinderien For  every output  of  **new_order** which is  just an ordered list of  IDs, I transform them to  a dataframe. Once that is  done, I try merge them to a larger dataset based on the ID that appears first grouped by another variable. That's the reason why IDs 1,2,3,4,5 are likely to result in something different  to 2,3,4,1,5. At the end, it  will just be the sum of another variable  based on this match. The biggest issue is  here  new_order = ID_order[:i] + [IDs[i]] + ID_order[i+1:] for me.

Comment: You can simply replace it in place ( `ID_order[i], t = IDs[i], ID_order[i]` ) and then restore it ( `ID_order[i] = t` ) after the evaluation.

Comment: Thanks  @ken for the response. That would give a list of  3 IDs, in each iteration, right?

Comment: No, it is not. It is a swap expression in python ( `a, b = b, a` ). You can do the same thing with two assignment statements if you like ( `t = ID_order[i]; ID_order[i] = IDs[i]` ). Note that using the swap expression is not what I am suggesting. Eliminating the copy of the list by in-place replacement is.

Comment: I can't figure this out clearly @ken.  How  can I incorporate this  in my code?

Comment: @Hummer remember to put those additional details [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), not just in a comment.